# Laravel required_without validation rule in array

Tags: arrays, laravel, validationrules, required-field

Let's say i have an object composed of `property_a` and `property_b`, and when submitted have to receive at least one of those two properties.
If the object were just one i could use the `required_without` validation rule as follow

```
return [
    'property_a' => ['required_without:property_b'],
    'property_b' => ['required_without:property_a'],
];
```

If my object were itself inside another one it would be easy using the dotted notation:

```
return [
    'parent_object.property_a' => ['required_without:parent_object.property_b'],
    'parent_object.property_b' => ['required_without:parent_object.property_a'],
];
```

But how can i use this validation rule with an array of object?

```
return [
    'array.*.property_a' => ['required_without:???.property_b'],
    'array.*.property_b' => ['required_without:???.property_a'],
];
```

Documentation for [required_without](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-required-without) don't explicit say nothing about my use case.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you post an example of your payload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In validation array works both for keys and values, so you can use `*` even in the rules.

So try this:

```
return [
    'array.*.property_a' => ['required_without:array.*.property_b'],
    'array.*.property_b' => ['required_without:array.*.property_a'],
];
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: Thanks so much. Wasn't aware of this. Especially that the "*" references "the same" element internally while iterating.